# OS X - how to preserve after-segue-view-controller's data(NSArray or NSMutableArray)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am a new to OS X. I had create a OS X application that is about simple waiting system.

If click the sendString button, string in the TextField is send to the next scene. (Action segue is Show)

the First View Controller :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
      WaitScene *destinationScene = [segue destinationController];
      destinationScene.receivedString = _textField.stringValue;
}
```

the Second View Controller :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear{
      _myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
      [_myArray addObject:_receivedString];
      _labelNOW.stringValue = _myArray[0];
}
```

Each time click the button, myArray seems to return to initial state. I guess i shouldn't use viewWillAppear. How can i presenve myArray's strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-creating a new empty `NSMutableArray` each time `viewWillAppear` is called. To prevent this, simply be sure to create the `_myArray` array only once.

Change the Second View Controller to look like the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear{
      if (_myArray == nil) _myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
      // _myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
      [_myArray addObject:_receivedString];
      _labelNOW.stringValue = _myArray[0];
}
```

When the second view controller is first created, the value for `_myArray` is `nil`. In this updated code, you check to see if `_myArray` is equal to `nil`, and only create an `NSMutableArray` if it is. On subsequent calls to `viewWillAppear`, `_myArray` is not `nil`, so the code simply continues to use the same `_myArray`.

Comment: Thank you! It really helped.